# what is the right place for Marquee in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, marquee

I have a project on Android Studio where the user has a grid and selects option from the grid. The grid has both an image and text describing the image under it. I tested marquee out on a separate project with plain text and it works. Any suggestions on what I may try? This is the XML file where marquee is to be applied.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/imageButtonLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ticker_section"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:freezesText="false"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```